# Login Redirect to Signup page

Tags: vidyo

When I try to login in to [vidyo.io](https://developer.vidyo.io/#/login-widget) it's redirect me to a signup page. But already I have an account. I don't know why it's happening.

Yesterday it was working fine.

I tried clearing my browsing data, cookies and using a different system, but the issue is not yet fixed. Without signing in I can't reach Vidyo support team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted support. They are aware of the issue and are working on it.

> [Edited] (VidyoCloud)
>   Sep 25, 6:01 AM EDT
>
> Hello [Edited],
>
> Apologies for this inconvenience. We are aware of this issue and we are working towards a resolution.
>   As soon as this is fixed, we will let you know.
>
> Thank you,
>
> [Edited]
>
> Stay up to date on Vidyo's services with our status page. Bookmark or subscribe at https://status.vidyo.com

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed. You should be able to login now.
Our apologies for the inconveniences caused.